# RVM doesn't work for 1.9.1 but works for 1.8.6 and 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, sqlite, readline, libxml2, rvm

**UPDATE 6/25/10**

Using [Google](http://niwos.com/2010/03/19/rvm-on-osx-snow-leopard-readline-errors/), I am not the only person to encounter this problem. Apparently this problem has to do with **readline**. Has anyone out there encountered this issue? (see error at make.error.log below) As google suggests, I compiled readline:

```
curl -O ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/readline/readline-6.1.tar.gz
tar xzvf readline-6.1.tar.gz
cd readline-6.1
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install
```

---

**Update II**

Following the advice of the above update (compile readline), has led me to new problems associated with libxml2, described in detail [here](http://groups.google.com/group/rubyversionmanager/browse_thread/thread/08e291cb58ee6994). I ran this command: `sudo port install libxml2`

---

**Update III 6/26/10**

After compiling readline, and following the steps outlined at the [RVM Documentation](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/packages/readline/) for Readline I'm met with a new error: (rvm install 1.8.7 and rvm install 1.9.1 produces this error)

This command: `rvm install 1.9.1 -C --with-readline-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr`
results in this:

```
main.c: In function ‘objcdummyfunction’:
main.c:19: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘objc_msgSend’
main.c: At top level:
main.c:19: warning: ‘objcdummyfunction’ defined but not used
eval.c: In function ‘ruby_cleanup’:
eval.c:139: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘ruby_init_stack’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
gc.c: In function ‘garbage_collect_with_gvl’:
gc.c:597: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
w: illegal option -- L
usage: w [hi] [user ...]
make: [libruby.1.9.1.dylib] Error 1 (ignored)
ld: in /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.dylib, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [../../.ext/i386-darwin10.4.0/tcltklib.bundle] Error 1
make: *** [mkmain.sh] Error 1
```

---

### **SOLUTION!!!! Update IV 6/27/10**

I was able to get rvm to function by doing 3 things. See a similar problem [here](http://accidentaltechnologist.com/ruby-on-rails/setting-up-sqlite3-for-ruby-on-rails-development/) :

1. I navigated to usr/local/lib/
2. `sudo rm -rf libsqlite3.dylib` **(Caution this could be a really bad thing to do; but it worked to solve this problem)**
3. I did `sudo port upgrade --force sqlite3 +universal` and got sqlite3 and all its dependencies to build x86_64/i386 universal libraries

All Green:
.

```
justinz$ rvm remove 1.9.1

info: Removing /Users/justinz/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.1-p378...

info: it seems that /Users/justinz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p378 is already non existent.

info: Removing ruby-1.9.1-p378 aliases...

info: Removing ruby-1.9.1-p378 wrappers...

info: Removing ruby-1.9.1-p378 environments...

info: Removing ruby-1.9.1-p378 binaries...
justin-zollarss-mac-pro:ruby-1.9.1-p378 justinz$ rvm install 1.9.1 -C --with-readline-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr

info: Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/justinz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p378

info: Extracting ruby-1.9.1-p378 ...

info: Configuring ruby-1.9.1-p378, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

info: Compiling ruby-1.9.1-p378, this may take a while, depending on your cpu(s)...

info: Installing ruby-1.9.1-p378

info: Installation of ruby-1.9.1-p378 is complete.

info: Updating rubygems for /Users/justinz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378

info: adjusting shebangs for ruby-1.9.1-p378 (gem irb erb ri rdoc testrb rake).

info: Importing initial gems...
justin-zollarss-mac-pro:ruby-1.9.1-p378 justinz$ rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-1.8.6-p399 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.8.7-p299 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.1-p378 [ x86_64 ]

justin-zollarss-mac-pro:ruby-1.9.1-p378 justinz$
```

---

I'm running into problems properly setting up [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/), I am really interested in using RVM, but it aborts after I attempt to install a new version of ruby; can you see anything wrong with my Bashrc or Profile file(s)?

Many Thanks in advance!

**Bash Terminal**

```
justin-zollarss-mac-pro:~ justinz$ rvm install 1.9.1

Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/justinz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p378

/Users/justinz/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.1-p378 has already been extracted.

Configuring ruby-1.9.1-p378, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

Compiling ruby-1.9.1-p378, this may take a while, depending on your cpu(s)...

Error running 'make ', please check /Users/justinz/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.1-p378/make*.log

There has been an error while running make. Aborting the installation.
```

**Bashrc**

```
# System-wide .bashrc file for interactive bash(1) shells.
if [ -z "$PS1" ]; then
   return
fi
PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '
# Make bash check its window size after a process completes
shopt -s checkwinsize
if [[ -s /Users/justinz/.rvm/scripts/rvm ]] ; then source /Users/justinz/.rvm/scripts/rvm ; fi
```

**make.error.log**

```
[2010-05-25 23:14:45] make 
readline.c: In function ‘username_completion_proc_call’:
readline.c:1159: error: ‘username_completion_function’ undeclared (first use in this function)
readline.c:1159: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
readline.c:1159: error: for each function it appears in.)
make[1]: *** [readline.o] Error 1
make: *** [mkmain.sh] Error 1
```

**Profile**

```
# System-wide .profile for sh(1)

if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
 eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi

if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
 [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
fi
if [[ -s /Users/justinz/.rvm/scripts/rvm ]] ; then source /Users/justinz/.rvm/scripts/rvm ; fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION!!!!**
I was able to get rvm to function by doing 3 things:

1. Navigate to `usr/local/lib/`
2. `sudo rm -rf libsqlite3.dylib` (Caution this could be a really bad thing to do; but it worked to solve this problem)
3. `sudo port upgrade --force sqlite3 +universal` and got sqlite3 and all its dependencies to build x86_64/i386 universal libraries

Answer (score 2):

According to [this post](http://eddorre.com/posts/using-ruby-enterprise-edition-and-passenger-on-os-x-with-rvm), you should install readline first:

```
rvm package install readline
```

Comment: While this wasn't the solution for the original poster, it worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: install and use (!) 1.8.7 first.

$ rvm install 1.8.7

$ rvm use 1.8.7

Then try installing 1.9.1 again.