# Do I simply delete the bashrc 'return' command?

Tags: rvm, bash

I've been advised to remove the [return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910507/setting-up-rvm-using-bash) command from my bashrc file in order to allow Ruby Version Manager to function properly. Do I simply delete the return command, or do I replace it with some other command? I am hesitant to mess with my System-wide shell without some proper direction. But I would really like to get RVM working as it is a time saver.

My bashrc is located in the etc directory and looks like this:

```
# System-wide .bashrc file for interactive bash(1) shells.
if [ -z "$PS1" ]; then
   return
fi

PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '
# Make bash check its window size after a process completes
shopt -s checkwinsize
if [[ -s /Users/justinz/.rvm/scripts/rvm ]] ; then source /Users/justinz/.rvm/scripts/rvm ; fi
```

The last line, is an insert, described in the RVM [installation](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't. That `return` is probably there for a good reason. It obviously doesn't want to execute anything after that if the `PS1` variable is empty.

I would just move the inserted line up above the `if` statement.

---

In addition, if that's actually in the *system-wide* `bashrc` file, you should be using something like:

```
${HOME}/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

rather than:

```
/Users/justinz/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

I'm sure Bob and Alice don't want to run *your* startup script.

If it's actually your `bashrc` file (in `/Users/justinz`), you can ignore that last snippet above.

Comment: Note to self and others in the future, this did not solve the issue but it is a correct answer. Don't mess with the return, its there for good reason.

Answer (score 1):

The last line uses a file in a specific user's home directory, and as such should not be in the system-wide bashrc, since only root and that user will have access to that file. Best to place it in that user's `~/.bashrc` instead.

Comment: Where is the user's .bashrc file or is this something I should create for this user? I've looked everywhere

Comment: It would be in `~`, the user's home directory.